# Invite Facebook friends using google play game services invite callbacks

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, google-play-games, multiplayer

I have made a RealTime and TurnBased Multiplayer Game(Android). Everything works good. I am using the

```
    getSelectOpponentIntent()
```

from the Google Play Game Services to invite/challenge the friends. That has been deprecated by Google since August 2016 but still I used it to get the list of opponents.

The only problem using Google Play Game is, there are very limited number of users who have accounts on G+, as it fetches the friend list from G+ only.

I have tried using the Facebook Game Services but unfortunately, currently they do not provide the Apis for Realtime Game Play(By real Time I mean synchronous playing). There are other third part providers like nextpeer.com (each having its own pros and cons) but I love the way Google Play Game Services Work(as it fulfils all my requirements). Sending/Receiving Invitations work in a perfect way.

Now what I am thinking is, to Use Google Play services for gameplay and invitations while using Facebook friends or friends from my contact list.
 I mean instead of using

```
    getSelectOpponentIntent()
```

I want invitations/challenges to be sent in a following way.

Step 1: Open my custom Activity in which I list all my Facebook friends or all my contacts.

Step 2: Select the friends from the list.

Step 3: save the selected friends in a Arraylist.

Step 4: Pass on the list to Room Configuration Callback using Google Play Game Services like this.

```
    rtmConfigBuilder.addPlayersToInvite(invitees);
```

I have searched a lot on this issue but didn't get any proper help. I have also started the implementation on my own but not sure whether google play services will be able to handle the manual friend list or not.

Any suggestions and help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our SO Question Checklist to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Please paste a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you have already tried.

Comment: I have done a complete reaserch on this topic and after that I am asking the question. Anyone there to answer?